# Error while getting image from folder using Angularjs 1.5 and php

Tags: php, angularjs

This error I am having;

```
GET http://localhost/~abhishek/Product/uploads/users/%7B%7Busers.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

... but the main reason to ask this question is; I am building product application and I have to store images in database and folder. so, I am getting that. images are loading in my web page but this errors are coming, please help me fix this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is because, it is trying to search for this path.
PHP is not substituting the **users.image** string with proper values.

```
http://localhost/~abhishek/Product/uploads/users/{{users.image}}
```

is the decoded form of URL in the above error.

```
http://localhost/~abhishek/Product/uploads/users/%7B%7Busers.image%7D%7D
```